# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "rails_dev"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I run `rails db:setup`, I get this error message:

> FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "rails_dev"
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"myapp_test", "username"=>"rails_dev", "password"=>"aqwe123", "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>5432}
>   rails aborted!
>
> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "rails_dev"
>   /home/whitehat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in 'initialize'
>   /home/whitehat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in 'new'
>   /home/whitehat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in 'connect

Comment: Can you paste your database.yml here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search, I found the solution; the issue was in the PostgreSQL configuration file `pg_hba.conf`. I changed the `ident` method to `MD5` and it worked.

```
local   all             all                                     MD5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            MD5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 MD5
```